# How to use vendor.ts from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

According to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html you should be able to add vendors like jquery in the vendor.ts file

```
// Other vendors for example jQuery, Lodash or Bootstrap
// You can import js, ts, css, sass, ...
```

what i have done so far

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
npm install jquery --save
```

and i added this line to vendor.ts

```
import 'jquery'
```

webpack run without an error. But I am not able to use jQuery in my Component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-widget',
  templateUrl: 'table-widget.component.html'
})

export class TableWidgetComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef) {

 }

 ngOnInit() : void {
   $(this._elRef.nativeElement).find('button').on('click', function() { alert("it works");  });
 }
}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose the jQuery to the global context.

Either of these options will achieve what you need to do.

In your webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    ....  //your other configs
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    })
]
```

Or using [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader)

```
module: {
  loaders: [
      { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery" },
  ]
}
```