# Using Jquery in Angular2 components

Tags: angular

In my node js application , I have installed jquery node module.
In order to use jquery in my angular2 components I have to include
below statement in ALL my  components.

```
const $ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

I am using webpack for module loading.

My question is Is this the correct way of implemention

OR

should I follow any other approach ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599997/how-to-use-vendor-ts-from-https-angular-io-docs-ts-latest-guide-webpack-html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637260/how-to-add-jquery-plugins-using-webpack#answer-39638594

Comment: @yurzui [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack) link is helpfull

Comment: Thanks :) So you have answered your own question